# Glass mapper does not filter items that have "Hide versions" checked?

Tags: glass-mapper

Is there a way to make Glass Mapper to filter out items which have "Hide versions" standard field checked?

Comment: What glass mapper version are you using? There is an issue on glass mapper 5 that displays items even if the version count is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId={GUID})]
public class YourCustomModelClass : GlassBase 
{
    [SitecoreField("__Hide version")]
    public virtual bool HideVersion{ get; set; }
}
```

by putting it into the required class or in the parent class you have already standard field properties are available.